Error pops up when I manually refresh my tab
Previously I have hosted my website in S3 using Web hosting, problem in s3 webhosting It will be access to the public.
So, I configured VPC endpoint, ALB and with S3
everything works fine all the API and routing.
Problem is when I manually refresh the browser tab.
Error pops up
Error
NoSuchKey
The specified key does not exist
pod

This can be handled when we are using S3 as webhosting configuring index = index.html and error = index.html
I followed this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/hosting-internal-https-static-websites-with-alb-s3-and-privatelink/
configured ALB with wildcard still the issue persist.
need an optimal solution

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Error
NoSuchKey
The specified key does not exist
pod
this error you got in the browser ?
could share the code where code that error ? also if applicable index.html code
